# Fastest way to get mean value from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, mean

`print (data_Week)` gives me :

```
{'2016-04-09 00:56': ['12.0', '50.7'], '2016-04-08 05:23': ['15.4', '49.8'], '2016-04-....}
```

The values are `Temperature` and `Humidity` values.

I'd like to get the `average` values from the dictionary `data_Week`.

The method I'm using works but it takes forever on my raspberry pi....

```
for date,value in data_Week.items():
    temp_first_value_Week = float(value[0])
    temp_total_Week += temp_first_value_Week
    temp_length_Week += 1
    hum_first_value_Week = float(value[1])
    hum_total_Week += hum_first_value_Week
    hum_length_Week += 1
if temp_length_Week > 1:
    tempAverage_Week = temp_total_Week/temp_length_Week
    tempAverage_Week = "%.2f" % tempAverage_Week
tempAverage_Week = str(tempAverage_Week)+'\xb0C'
if hum_length_Week > 1:
    humAverage_Week = hum_total_Week/hum_length_Week
    humAverage_Week = "%.2f" % humAverage_Week
humAverage_Week = str(humAverage_Week)+'%'
```

there's a dictionary entry every minute and I'm trying to get average values from a week.
So there are 1440 Temperature Values and 1440 Humidity Values per day..... 10080 values per week.
Is there a smart way to get the average values.
The method from above takes the pi around `15 minutes`

Edit:
I found out, that the script took so long because I looped over the dictionary which was not necessary as [BHawk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4434679/bhawk) mentioned in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605776/5239927).

I going to use the [One Liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605702/5239927) from [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman). It works perfect.
And thanks for the Pandas [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36605750/5239927). Maybe if the current version is going to slow down again I'm going to switch to it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt your raspberry pi would process only 11 dict entries per second. Maybe the dict contains more data than you think, or the inefficiency is in some other spot, or the box is busy?

Comment: I started logging data and at 7.p.m, I get an email from the pi with `max`, `min` and `average` values over a period of 7 Days. When starting logging the first mail only had values from approx. 14 hours , and after some days of logging it slowed down... now that there is always a period of 7 days in the log file it nearly always takes that much time... the problem might be that i not only calc average for a week but also for the last 24 hours....

Comment: Shoud your calculations ever get too slow, an efficient approach may be to use an "online" algorithm that updates your results incrementally whenever a new data point arrives. For calculation of min, max, [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm), that's easy to do and spreads the calculation overhead so much that it becomes unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to increment the number of entries each time you read a value. You don't need to cast to float when reading the values, they are already floats.

Try:

```
week_length = len(data_Week.keys())
if week_length > 1:
    tempAverage_Week = sum([x for x,y in data_Week.values()])/weekLength
    humAverage_Week = sum([y for x,y in data_Week.values()])/weekLength
```

Comment: Well, in the question, the values are not already floats. Also, the first line should be `week_length = len(data_Week)`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if all you want is the average of the temperatures then a 1-line solution should be possible and should run fast:

```
>>> d = {'2016-04-09 00:56': ['12.0', '50.7'], '2016-04-08 05:23': ['15.4', '49.8']}
>>> sum(float(x) for x,y in d.values())/len(d)
13.7
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pandas? I think it could perform better for this volume and type of data/operations you're doing. For example, I saved you sample data in a json file and ran the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("data.json", "r") as handle:
  x = pd.read_json(handle, orient='index')

print("Data:")
print(x)
print("Description:")
print(x.describe()) # Will print a summary of each column
```

Result

```
Data:
                        0     1
2016-04-08 05:23:00  15.4  49.8
2016-04-09 00:56:00  12.0  50.7
Description:
               0          1
count   2.000000   2.000000
mean   13.700000  50.250000
std     2.404163   0.636396
min    12.000000  49.800000
25%    12.850000  50.025000
50%    13.700000  50.250000
75%    14.550000  50.475000
max    15.400000  50.700000
```

Comment: pandas is definitely a natural choice for this sort of problem, though the need to run on a Raspberry Pi might place constraints on the size of libraries which can be used in the solution.